# Чем отличаются два этих способа ловли ошибок?

Tags: javascript

```
// Нехорошо:
try {
    // ...
} catch(e) {
    if (! e instanceof MyError) {
        throw e;
    }
    // ...
}

// Хорошо:
try {
    // ...
} catch(e if e instanceof MyError) {
    // ...
}
```

По-моему это ведь одно и тоже, только во втором случае используется нестандартный синтаксис.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ничем не отличаются, кроме того, что второй способ не будет работать во всех браузерах и средах.
Вот что по этому поводу [говорит MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch):

> Эта возможность не является стандартной и стандартизировать её пока никто не собирается. Не используйте её на сайтах, смотрящих во внешний мир: она будет работать не у всех пользователей. Также могут присутствовать большие несовместимости между реализациями и её поведение может в будущем измениться.